# jython and jython-apt

Tags: jython, apt

i am trying to get jython running with the apt-module from python.

I have standard python2.7 installed as well as jython2.7. When running `import apt` in python everything is ok, but when running it in jython the module is not found. When extending the sys.path to the python2.7-installation like `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` the apt-package is found but it complains about not finding the apt-pkg-package (which is just some simple .so-file and not a real "package" in python).

What can be done here?

Answer (score 1):

`apt_pkg` is required by apt, and only implemented as a binary module. Unfortunately, jython [cannot load these](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo#Is_Jython_the_same_language_as_Python.3F), so you're out of luck. You can either port apt_pkg to Java (you can simply create a shim with [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/)), to pure Python, or use another mechanism (for example calling an apt frontend on the commandline and parsing its outputs).

Comment: My goal is: To use the apt-binding of python to avoid parsing any command line output just to install a package out of a java frontend or to read information about the packages installed. The best way in this case would be to call real python-scripts out of java in the command line, let them write their output somewhere as JSON-file (or something else) and let java read this output to see what happened or to get the information needed for a given task.